# Memory leaks on ios 10.x simulator and devices

Tags: c#, xamarin, memory-leaks, xamarin.ios, profiler

In our legacy project we are struggling with a strange problem: there is a memory leak which occurs on iOS 10.x (at first memory warning signal received then app crashes), but everything is fine on iOS 9.3. Both simulators and devices show same behaviour.

I can't debug it with XCode Instruments due to [known deadlock problem.](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/21656/)
But I was able to see that there is really a problem by use of Xamarin Profiler.

[image]
*Clearly seen 9.3-sim (top) releases used memory, but 10.0 (bottom) doesn't!. (some offset in time of memory pressure is seen because I hit the button later then at the first time)*

[image]
*Memory allocation history (with dead objects). 9.3 - left. 10.0 - right.*

[image]
*Memory allocation history (only live objects). 9.3 - left. 10.0 - right.*

[image]
*Byte array objects for 10.0 simulator. They are alive! But list of paths to root is empty! :-(*

[image]
*Same objects for 9.3 simulator. They are dead as expected to be.*

And now look at the call tree for one of those byte-array objects:
[image]
This is a 9.3 sim. After the call of the method AsJpeg(System.nfloat), as expected NativeBitmap.Dispose() is called.

But how looks call tree for 10.0 simulator?
[image]
Aaaaand there is no Dispose() call :-(

But if I put breakpoint in Dispose method it's hited. Or if I put console output in Dispose's last line it's also printed.
I think something breaks when AsJpeg method called.

I've created a sample project that reproduces the issue [github.com/..../iosleaktest](https://github.com/lexboss93/iosleaktest). Screens are taken from it (commit sha 8985627214e6ca259c4ffb835211eaf9550e3805)

I don't know what to do further. I am suspecting this is a xamarin bug. Will try to report a bug.

**UPD (04.04.2017):**
Created a bug report:
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=54443

Also after upgradging xamarin, xcode and os got new available iOS system - 10.3 (14E269) - and it isn't affected by memory leak.

Comment: I confirm that I've found exactly the same problem. It worked well in the 9.x and it works well again in the 10.3.